# PHP : Dropdown not insert into table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where the form contains textfield and dropdown menu . But the problem is , after I fill in the field and select the option . Only the data from textfield is inserted into table on db . The selected option is not inserted to db . I already checked my code , but can't find any error.. Please help me out . Thanks .

**FORM :**

```
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><strong>Name</strong>
        <div id="div_nama"><input name="txt_nama" type="text" id="txt_nama" onchange="validate()" size="40" />
        </div>      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><strong>Kod MASCO</strong>
        <div id="div_kod_masco"><select name="txt_kod_masco" id="txt_kod_masco">
        <option>Sila Pilih</option>
    <?php 
        $sql = " SELECT * FROM lstmasco ORDER BY kod ASC";
        $res_kod = mysql_query($sql);
        while($row_kod = mysql_fetch_array($res_kod)){
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo strtolower($row_kod['nama']); ?>"><?php echo ($row_kod['kod']); ?></option>
    <?php 
        }
    ?>
        </select>
        </div></td></tr>
```

I shortened the form code out .

**MYSQL QUERY:**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO jobseeker(`no_kp`, `tahun_lahir`, `nama`, `alamat`, `poskod`, `daerah`, `negeri`, `kod_masco`, `kod_lesen`, `tel_bimbit`, `tel_rumah`, `email`, `jantina`, `status`, `sumber`, `dt_daftar`, `active`) 
    VALUES('".strtolower($nokp_edited)."', '".$year."', '".addslashes(strtoupper($_POST['txt_nama']))."', 
    '".addslashes(strtoupper($_POST['txt_alamat']))."', 
    '".$poskod."', '".$daerah."', '".$negeri."', '".addslashes($_POST['txt_kod_masco'])."',
    '".addslashes($_POST['txt_kod_lesen'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['txt_tel_bimbit'])."', 
    '".addslashes($_POST['txt_tel_rumah'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['txt_email'])."', 
    '".addslashes($_POST['txt_jantina'])."', '".addslashes($_POST['txt_status'])."', 
    '".addslashes($_POST['txt_sumber'])."', '".date('Y-m-d')."', '".$active."')";
    $res_updjobseeker = mysql_query($sql);
    $no_kp = strtolower($nokp_edited);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a value on first "option". If you select "Sila Pilih" from dropdown, a value sent to the server will be null.

Comment: but if i select one of the option, it still doesn't inserted into the table

Comment: Can you make a dump(var_dump or print_r) of $_POST in order to see what is inside  print_r($_POST)